# How can I get Gradle ant logging to work?

Tags: logging, ant, gradle

When I run this with `gradlew deployJelastic` I get no output.

```
task deployJelastic() {
    logging.level = LogLevel.INFO
    ant.taskdef(name: 'jelastic', classname: 'com.jelastic.Jelastic', classpath: configurations.jelastic.asPath)
    ant.jelastic(email: "foo",
            password: "bar",
            dir: "",
            filename: "baz-1.0.war",
            context: "",
            environment: "env",
            apihoster: "app.whelastic.net") {
    }
}
```

If I run the task with `gradlew deployJelastic -i` I get all the ant output I'm looking for.

I do not want to change the logging output for any other task, but for some reason I can't get this gradle recommended approach to work.

From Gradle's logging page. http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/logging.html

To change the log level for standard out or error during task execution, tasks also provide a LoggingManager.

Which is what I'm accessing and setting here. `logging.level = LogLevel.INFO`

I'm executing from the command line with this setup.

```
Build time:   2014-11-24 09:45:35 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     6fcb59c06f43a4e6b1bcb401f7686a8601a1fb4a

Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_71 (Oracle Corporation 24.71-b01)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work like this. Apparently the stuff inside the { } is the configuration of the task. That's where you want to do things that call setters on the task object. The doLast is a closure that accepts a collection of commands to execute. So if you use this form, you define a task, do all the task configuration at the top, and then in the doLast { } closure you write any code the task is suppose to execute.

I find this extremely confusing, but after stumbling through a few dozen iterations of task definitions I found this one to be the best. BTW, I have no idea how doLast interacts with additional task actions tacked on by using the << operator, so your mileage may vary. I don't know if doLast is just appending to the last spot in the task list when it's defined, or if it's some special spot that is guaranteed to be last.

```
task deployJelastic(name: 'deployJelastic', dependsOn: war) {
    logging.level = LogLevel.INFO
    def environmentSuffix = project.properties.enviromentSuffix ?: "test"
    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(name: 'jelastic', classname: 'com.jelastic.Jelastic', classpath: configurations.jelastic.asPath)
        ant.jelastic(email: "",
                password: "",
                dir: project.projectDir.absolutePath + "/build/libs/",
                filename: "ServeDirtyLibsInJava-${project.version}.war",
                context: "",
                environment: "foo-${environmentSuffix}",
                apihoster: "app.whelastic.net") //Got this from http://docs.jelastic.com/jelastic-hoster-info
    }
}
```